# How do you prove the converse Cantor's intersection theorem?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was given a proof in class on how to prove it in one direction, but I was wondering: is there a way you could prove that if the intersection of a decreasing sequence of closed sets with diameters tending to zero is nonempty, then the metric space is complete?

Answer (score 5):

Take a Cauchy sequence $\langle a_n\rangle $, and use the Cantor intersection property with the sets $\overline {A_n}$ where $$A_n=\{a_n,a_{n+1},\dots\}$$

---

**ADD** Firstly, we have to use that for any set $A$, $$\operatorname{diam}A=\operatorname{diam}\bar A$$

For each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that whenever $p,n>N$ we have $$|a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon$$

Thus   $\operatorname{diam}A=\operatorname{diam}\bar A\to 0$. By Cantor, $$\exists !x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \overline{A_n}$$

Take $\epsilon >0$. We want to show there exists $N$ such that $$|a_n-x|<\epsilon$$ whenever $n>N$.

Take $N$ large enough so that $m>n>N$  gives $$\operatorname{diam}\overline {A_m}<\operatorname{diam}\overline {A_n}<\frac\epsilon 2$$

Then if $n>N$, $$|x-a_n|\leq |x-a_m|+|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon \;\; \blacktriangle$$

Comment: d(xn,xn+k)<epsilon  then assume there exists p in the intersection of Fn where p is in the closure of every one of the sets such that every neighborhood of p intersects with every set . Then I know you would have to take the fact that p=lim (xn) but I don't know how that proves it

Comment: @user74912 I added something.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't sure if I could use the closure or not. This help a lot

Answer (score 4):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence, and for every $n$ let $i(n)$ be the least $n$ guaranteed by the definition of a Cauchy sequence such that $k,m\geq i(n)$ implies $d(x_k,x_m)<\frac1n$.

Now let $C_n$ be the closed ball $\overline B(x_{i(n)},\frac2n)$. Clearly this is a decreasing sequence of closed sets.

If its intersection is non-empty then it is some $x$ such that $\lim x_n=x$. Therefore every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Comment: that makes way more sense then what I was thinking thank you for the insight!

Comment: How do you see that the closed balls are decreasing?

Comment: @Bio: It's a Cauchy sequence, and the distances are chosen appropriately.